# The instructions a Stack Machine has

Tags: computer-architecture, assembly

Trying to figure out which instructions a stack machine has, and wanted to clarify / reassure that these are in fact all of them.

- `push` onto stack
- `pop` off stack
- `call` a system function like `add`

Then you can implement `jump`, for example, by pushing the address of the instruction in memory, and calling `call`. You can implement `add` by pushing twice and popping twice, etc. You can implement everything from just these 3 instructions. Wondering if this is correct, or if there is anything I am missing.

Comment: There is no single canonical stack machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are dozens and dozens of stack machines out there in the wild, and they all have different instruction sets. So there's no single correct answer.

Some people might consider using `CALL` like that cheating: after all, it relies on things like `ADD` and `CMP` and `JMP` and `DUP` and such all being implemented in the machine, so why don't you call them instructions? But if you're going that route, you can get rid of `POP` too, and implement that with `CALL`. The only reason you can't get rid of `PUSH` too is you need some way to get opcodes and arguments onto the stack.

If you don't want to use `CALL` like that, the minimum for Turing-completeness would be something like `PUSH`, `ROT` (rotate the stack in some controllable way), `DUP` (duplicate the top of the stack), `CMP` (compare two values), `JMP` (some sort of conditional GOTO), and `SUB` (subtract one number from another). An actually useful machine would have more, things like `ADD` and `AND` and such.